# How to add the data of this table in markers (pop-up) on map?

Tags: pandas, jupyter-notebook, google-maps-markers, folium

I imported this table from Excel into Jupyter. I was using pandas for this. But now I want to mark markers with cities from table below on my map with  popups with the data from colognes A1,A2,A3 and I don't know how to do this.

Example: I press on a definite marker and after this the popup appears with this data from colognes A1,A2,A3.

Image 1:

[image: Image 1]

Image 2:

[image: Image 2]

Can you tell me the corresponding code for this operation?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

To display the pop-up in tabular form at each location, a loop process is performed on each row of the data frame, converting one row from a series to a data frame, and then transposing it. I also adjust the width of the data frame.

```
import pandas as pd
import io
import folium

data = '''
Name A1 A2 A3 LAT LON
"Malibu Beach" 0.63 0.55 0.95 34.03194 -118.698387
Commerce 0.17 0.45 0.25 34.00031 -118.159770
"Long Beach" 0.19 0.21 0.09 33.77171 -118.181310
'''
df = pd.read_csv(io.StringIO(data), delim_whitespace=True)

import folium

m = folium.Map([df.LAT.mean(), df.LON.mean()], zoom_start=8)

for i in range(len(df)):
    html = df.loc[i,['Name','A1','A2','A3']].to_frame().T.to_html(
        classes="table table-striped table-hover table-condensed table-responsive"
    )
    popup = folium.Popup(html, max_width=500)
    folium.Marker([df.iloc[i]['LAT'], df.iloc[i]['LON']], popup=popup).add_to(m)

m
```

[image]

Comment: Thanl you for these details. I tried to imitate this code but I got this glitch https://drive.google.com/file/d/1ojIw_Lpxiq8z0cy9QKsmTTTGvxxP7msH/view?usp=drive_link

Comment: The only difference is the name of the data frame, which in your case is `data`. I am `df`.

Comment: Sorry, I completed all but I see one marker in Long Beach.  https://drive.google.com/file/d/1E6ZiQLVIBQpBTncP523Z-ekHo354_bS1/view?usp=sharing,   https://drive.google.com/file/d/1yRYstk35IcgzwPAjUZhCLnVBw0QqwRMF/view?usp=sharing

Comment: The unit of execution must be the entire loop process. One cell must contain all of the following. `for i in range(len(df)):
    html = df.loc[i,['Name','A1','A2','A3']].to_frame().T.to_html(
        classes="table table-striped table-hover table-condensed table-responsive"
    )
    popup = folium.Popup(html, max_width=500)
    folium.Marker([df.iloc[i]['LAT'], df.iloc[i]['LON']], popup=popup).add_to(m)`

Comment: Or you can put my answer in one cell and run it.

Comment: Hello again. Sorry for worrie. I would like to ask you about displaying this data. Can Idisplay this imported data not in the form of a table but in the form of strings in Jupyter or maybe another form exist ?(Example:https://drive.google.com/file/d/1UqOKKDvKr_LkDj7k5bVYgP-H0mGicIXT/view?usp=drive_link)

Comment: Here's an [example](https://nbviewer.org/github/python-visualization/folium/blob/main/examples/Popups.ipynb): the HTML popup is what you're looking for.

Comment: Ok. This is an appropriate example. I want to say thanks to you for responsiveness. I wish you good luck